# Entity Framework looses relational mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have isolated a problem I am having in a small worker service project.
I have created a code-first DB as follows:

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DBContext()
        {

        }
        public DBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<SubClass>()
                .HasOne(t => t.ParentClass)
                .WithMany(s => s.Subs);
        }

        public DbSet<TestClass> TestClasses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubClass> SubClasses { get; set; }
    }

public class TestClass
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public ICollection<SubClass> Subs { get; set; } = new List<SubClass>();
    }

public class SubClass
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";

        [ForeignKey("ParentClass")]
        public Guid? ParentClassID { get; set; }
        public TestClass? ParentClass { get; set; }
    }
```

The DB is created on startup. First i start a thread that populates some data into the DB:

```
using (var scope = _factory.CreateScope())
            {
                var _db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBContext>();
                if (!_db.TestClasses.Any())
                {
                    TestClass cls = new TestClass { Name = "Class1" };
                    cls.Subs.Add(new SubClass { Name = "SubClass1" });
                    _db.TestClasses.Add(cls); ;
                    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Created items");

                    cls = new TestClass();
                    cls = _db.TestClasses.First();
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Count is: {cls.Subs.Count}");

                }

            }
```

This seems to work fine, and the logger returns "Count is: 1"

Then I start another thread, to read out the data:

```
using (var scope = _factory.CreateScope())
            {
                var _db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DBContext>();


                TestClass cls = _db.TestClasses.First();
                _logger.LogInformation($"Second Count is: {cls.Subs.Count}");

            }
```

But now the Logger returns "Second count is: 0". The is no subclass in the list.
When I check the database, everything looks fine:

```
TestClass:
ID                                      Name
A1BEB353-D2CB-47BA-500C-08DA8FEADD1A    Class1

Subclass:
ID                                      Name        ParentClassID
46D06860-02D6-4192-867F-08DA8FEADD22    SubClass1   A1BEB353-D2CB-47BA-500C-08DA8FEADD1A
```

But when I read the TestClass out, it has no subs. Seems like the relation is lost somehow. Anyone have ideas?

If it helps, here is my migration:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "TestClasses",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_TestClasses", x => x.ID);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "SubClasses",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    ParentClassID = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_SubClasses", x => x.ID);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_SubClasses_TestClasses_ParentClassID",
                        column: x => x.ParentClassID,
                        principalTable: "TestClasses",
                        principalColumn: "ID");
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_SubClasses_ParentClassID",
                table: "SubClasses",
                column: "ParentClassID");
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: There is a separate section in the docs [dedicated to how to load related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, if the second time I extract the data, i have to specify

```
TestClass cls = _db.TestClasses.Include(c => c.Subs).First();
```

Now I get the subs out.
But I have not had to do this before in EF. Is this new or some form of option? In the ACTUAL project where i have this issue, i need to retrieve a full tree of items (not just 1 layer of subs), and i want to refer to them in code like:

```
LowestClass.Parent.Parent.Topclass.SomeProperty = ...
```

Do i have to "Include" all of them?
Doesn't seem to easy to get the next level of subs anyway, since i can't "Include" a subset of a subset...

I thought EF used lazy loading by default to handle these things? Seems like its using neither lazy nor eager loading, but just none at all.

Comment: [Lazy Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy). In EF Core lazy loading not used by default.

Comment: Yup, that solved it for me. Was unaware i had to actually specify this now. Thanks, Alexander Petrov! :)